# Setting click event with Javascript

Tags: javascript, click, onload

I am trying to make a click event with Javascript on this image button

```
<input type="image" alt="Skip" name="bt_cancel" id="bt_cancel" 
       src="http://images.eversave.com/Images/optin/skip_button_092106.gif" 
       onclick="return handleSubmit(this);">
```

I am trying to use it in Chrome but it doesn't respond when I load the page.
I am using the following code:

```
if((window.location.hostname == "eversave.com")){
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("bt_cancel").click();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code works absolutely fine, I think the problem is in the host name check. alert it to find out what it really is, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/AvgME/

```
<input type="image" alt="Skip" name="bt_cancel" id="bt_cancel" 
  src="http://images.eversave.com/Images/optin/skip_button_092106.gif" 
  onclick="return handleSubmit(this);">

<script>
if((window.location.hostname != "eversave.com")){
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("bt_cancel").click();
  }
}
function handleSubmit(f) {
    alert(window.location.hostname);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is in your case a good option.

The code would than look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bt_cancel').click(function(){
       // do some stuff with it like:
       alert($(this).attr('src'));
    });
});
```

Comment: can you use jquery in chrome/grasemoneky script?

Comment: I'm sure that you can use it in Chrome (as in all other browsers). Greasymonkey I don't know about but a quick search lead me to: http://joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey/, which looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You could just call the function:

```
handleSubmit(document.getElementById("bt_cancel"));
```

---

Btw. `return`ing the value in the image click handler has no effect. There is no default action associated with clicking on images.

Answer (score 0):

If the element is in the DOM on page-load, you can use this in the `head` of the document, otherwise put it after the `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var image = document.getElementByID('bt_cancel');

image.onclick = function(){
    handlesubmit(this);
};

</script>
```

Though in all fairness, I think I prefer [@Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359297/setting-click-event-with-javascript/7359365#7359365)'s answer.